# Multiprocessing pool in python took more time

Tags: python, time, multiprocessing, reduce, pool

So, I started learning multiprocessing in python. I created a pool for function 'res'. I was interested in time after run program using the pool and using normal way, I thought that if I use pool processing time would be reduced but as I see, pool took  10.0413179397583 sec(s) and normal way took 0.005002737045288086 sec(s). What did I miss?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def res(a):
    squ = 0
    for i in range(a):
        squ += i**2
    return squ

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = time.time()
    p = mp.Pool()
    result = p.map(res, range(10000))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(time.time()-t1)

    t2 = time.time()
    result = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        sum += i**2
        result.append(sum)
    print(time.time()-t2)
```

Comment: Um, your `pool` example is calculating `10000` different loops, from `0-9999` iterations each one. Your second example is a *single* loop, with `9999` iterations... regardless, the assumption that "if i use pool porcessing time would be reduce" is not a safe bet. There are many ways a multiprocessing approach would take more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you use with `multiprocessing` is `O(n^2)` (loop of 1, loop of 2, ... loop of 9999), while the "normal approach" is `O(n)`. Without `multiprocessing`, the first way took about 3 times longer in my tests.

Related: [What is a plain English explanation of “Big O” notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Your `pool` example is calculating `10000` different loops, from `0-9999` iterations each one. Your second example is a *single* loop, with `9999` iterations...

Here's an apples-to-apples approach:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import sys

NUM_ITER = int(sys.argv[1])
def res(a):
    squ = 0
    for i in range(a):
        squ += i**2
    return squ

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = time.time()
    p = mp.Pool(None)
    result = p.map(res, range(NUM_ITER))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print(f"With multiprocessing: {time.time()-t1}")

    t2 = time.time()
    result = [res(i) for i in range(NUM_ITER)]
    print(f"Without multiprocessing: {time.time()-t2}")
```

Note, `multiprocessing` will take longer because of the overhead unless you are doing a lot of iterations, so consider:

```
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ python -B timing_mp.py 100
With multiprocessing: 0.18288207054138184
Without multiprocessing: 0.002610921859741211
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ python -B timing_mp.py 1000
With multiprocessing: 0.1448049545288086
Without multiprocessing: 0.16153407096862793
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ python -B timing_mp.py 5000
With multiprocessing: 2.273800849914551
Without multiprocessing: 3.9749832153320312
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ python -B timing_mp.py 10000
With multiprocessing: 8.837619066238403
Without multiprocessing: 15.725339889526367
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent discussion of this in regard to the package *emcee* by [Dan Foreman-Mackey](https://github.com/dfm/emcee/blob/147484a28acbee1583325f42dfc3faad3033d379/docs/tutorials/parallel.rst).

If the computation time for the function call isn't relatively large compared to the overhead of multiprocessing you will find no advantage. You can demonstrate this relatively easily with a function call like the following

```
import time
def func():
    """ arbitrarily time-intensive function """
    time.sleep(1)   # return after 1 s "computation time"
    return
```